# *ngIf show button for row on ngx-datatable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I have a populated table and by default on load, one of the columns has a hidden element by a show button. I'm looking to show the input per row, but currently when the button is clicked, the hidden button shows all of the fields.

HTML Table -

```
<ngx-datatable
   class="material"
   rowHeight="auto"
   [loadingIndicator]="tableLoading"
   [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
   [rows]="rows"
   [headerHeight]="50"
   [footerHeight]="50"
   [limit]="30"
   [selected]="selected"
   [selectionType]="SelectionType.checkbox"
   [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false"
   (select)="onSelect($event)"
   [sorts]="[{prop: 'lastName', dir: 'asc'}]"
 >

<ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row">

 <ng-select
    *ngIf="singleItem"
    [multiple]="true"
    placeholder="Select a single medication to send"
    appendTo="body"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    [items]="row.medications.items"
    bindLabel="name"
    bindValue="id"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedMedications[row.id]">
 </ng-select>

<div *ngIf="!singleItem">
   <p class="btn btn-light" type="button" (click)="buttonSwitch([row.id])">
      Single item 
   </p>
</div>
```

TS -

```
singleItem: boolean;

buttonSwitch(row) {
  console.log(row);
  this.singleItem = true;
}
```

Once the button switch is clicked, the input field for only the row should appear.

Comment: Can you show the full code of your table and button?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `singleItem` or another named flag for each row. Right now you have one for all entries, that's why when you click on the button, it changes all rows.

On this `buttonSwitch` function, you're getting the `row` parameter and not using it. You should have something like this:

```
buttonSwitch(row) {
  row.singleItem = true;
  // Or the
  // row.singleItem = !row.singleItem;
  // To switch the value, and not only set as true
}
```

Then your `*ngIf` would be like this: `*ngIf="row.singleItem"`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting a logging of 'true' for the value but the *ngIf seems to be broken.